# Change filesystem blocksize when installing 15.10

Tags: filesystem, ext4, dd

so,
I'm very much out of my depth in the whole world of *nix here. I'm searching all over about file system block sizes, and I found [this script](https://github.com/tdg5/blog_snippets/tree/master/lib/blog_snippets/articles/tuning_dd_block_size) which determines what I can tell are read-speeds with different block sizes (for random data). I'm currently on Ubuntu 15.04, waiting for 15.10. This script tells me that (working with /dev/null), with a bs of `4k`, I get a `9.4GB/s` speed, and with a bs of `262144 bytes`, I get a speed of `20.2GB/s`. Again, I'm probably having delusions of computing grandeur, here, but does that mean that if I installed 15.10 with a block size of `262144 bytes` (because as far as I can tell, you can't just change it without recalculating a lot), it would... *blushes* run faster? And if so, how would I do that when I go to install it?
I'd love to learn a lot more about this, because it's all rather interesting. I don't mind being slapped in the face with facts! :)

Comment: First, don't mention 15.10 that often. It's not officially released and therefore still off-topic. Second, `/dev/null` is no real disk drive, but a virtual device. Its "speed" is in no way related to a physical disk. 200k block size for a hdd is not realistic.

Comment: Copying, would probably be faster, but it might depend on the type of copy. Same condition for write.  The minimum size in for an int is 2 bytes (using min, to ignore architecture differences) when your PC goes to assign some data to a disk location, it doesn’t say oh int, 2 bytes, it goes ok, lets start with a 4K block, and increase it if necessary. You could just as easily write data to disk in 512K blocks, but if all you’re writing is 2bytes, its a horrible use of space. Yes, it might run faster. it might also waste loads of disk space.

Comment: Thanks, @ByteCommander for that /dev/null fact. I thought it would kinda function as a normal file on my disk, but, okay.

Comment: And, @j0h, thanks for the insight into all of this. I kinda thought it might take up more space than needed, but I'd be willing to find a good trade off :)
I'd like to try it with an external device. How would I go about creating a filesystem, and specifying its bs permanently, do you know?

Comment: I think the system will handle this well enough automatically. That sounds like a very advanced setting, which I would not suggest you to change, especially as you showed that you're no expert in this special topic.

Comment: I meant on the external device, for testing. I won't bother with the next install I do.